# Google Buzz get user data from feed

Tags: php, curl, google-buzz

```
I am trying to access the user info or user id after authenticating the user. 
I have this url I call with 
curl_init(https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/people/@me/@self)
but it doesn't work. It says:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"><error>
<domain>GData</domain>
<code>authError</code>
<location type="header">Authorization</location>
<internalReason>@me called by anonymous</internalReason></error></errors>

So I added a key at the end
curl_init(https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/people/@me/@self?key="...")
But it says "Bad Request Access not Configured"..I am geting now where..
any ideas? THanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OAuth. You can't just make an unauthenticated HTTP request to the API. See the documentation on [authorization](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#auth) for the API. Also, the key parameter needs to be a developer key obtained from the [API Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console).

Comment: Yeah. I ended up using the Google Buzz class after no replies. Wasn't as bad as imagined. Thanks.